# Add controller dynamically to angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js into backbone js application. I have one controller( say  **controller1**) which is get added into angular app from one of the backbone view (say **view1**). Now I added another controller( say **controller2**), which is in another backbone view( say **view2**). From view2 i added **controller2** to angular app. But here **controller2's** constructor doesn't gets call.

**view1**

```
bootstarpAngular: function(){

        var app = angular.module('APP', []);
        app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', loadController1]);

        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                this.angular = angular.bootstrap(document, ['APP']);
        });
    }
```

**controller1**

```
function loadController1($scope){
   console.log("Controller1");
}
```

**view2**

```
addController2: function(){

            var app = angular.module('APP');
            app.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', loadController2]);
        }
```

**controller2**

```
function loadController2($scope){
   console.log("Controller2");
}
```

Here, console log prints only for **controller1** not for **controller2**.

i want both controllers get call. Am i doing wrong or any better approach is available to do this requirement.

Comment: angular doesn't have built in lazy load. Include all your components prior to bootstrapping angular

Comment: What does backbone.js has to do with this..? Please don't add irrelevant tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add controllers with `controller` function before bootstrapping Angular's app.

If you really need to lazy load a controller you can do, before bootstrap:

```
app.config(function($controllerProvider) {
  // globalCtrl must be a global function
  globalCtrl = $controllerProvider.register;
});
```

In your new module:

```
globalCtrl('Controller2', Controller2Fn);
```

There is usually a better solution to achieve this, but I don't know your exact situation.

Comment: Controller2 requires some data, which is in the view2 only. View1 doesn't have required data, due to this i can't add controller2 in view1.